# getting property 'retValue' of undefined error in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have following jquery plugin code on which I working on but it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retValue' of undefined`. Below is my code

```
(function ($) {
    var Plugin = {
        init: function (options, elem) {
            var self = this;
            self.elem = elem;
            self.$elem = $(elem);

            this.search = (typeof options === 'string') ? options:options.retValue;
            this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.options, options);
        }
    };

    $.fn.plugin = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var plugin = Object.create(Plugin);
            plugin.init(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.plugin.options = {
        retValue: 'value',
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#selector').plugin();
```

Here I am passing no parameters in border(). So I want my plugin to get the default `retValue` but it gives me above error. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I want to use this plugin in 3 following ways.

```
$('#selector').plugin(); // does not work
$('#selector').plugin('string'); // works
$('#selector').plugin({key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}); // works
```

**How can I make first one work?**

Comment: Anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) your settings:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, passedsettings);
```

This will automaticly merge your settings and fill it with defaults if none passed.

```
var Border = {
    init: function (options, elem) {
        var self = this;
        self.elem = elem;
        self.$elem = $(elem);
        self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.border.options, options);
        alert( self.options.retValue );
    }
};
```

And call plugin with options like:

```
$('#foo').border({ retValue : "abc" });
```

Or

```
$('#foo').border();
```

Comment: I am already using extend in my code. What is the difference between your code and mine?

Comment: That you are using the var `options` to set the `search` on a wrong way. And now I'm using the result of the `extend`. If you try this code. It will work.

Comment: Could you please take a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/p4Xkn/ . I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to remove this: `this.search = (typeof options === 'string') ? options:options.retValue;` because `options` is undefined and not `===` to a string. Which will try and return `options.retValue` and since `options` is `undefined` you will get the `undefined` error.

Comment: After following what you said now when I call my plugin like `$('#foo').border('new value');` it still shows me `value` instead of `new value`.

Comment: Parameters should be passed like in my example.

Comment: I want parameters to be passed in 3 ways. 2 your ways and one mentioned in my comment.